# Sql failing to calling fields correctly

Tags: php, sql

**The php/sql calling this:**

```
<?php
// Filter our input.
$pID = filter_input(INPUT_GET, 'pID', FILTER_SANITIZE_NUMBER_INT);
if(!$pID) {
    echo "No pID specified.";
    exit;
}
$username = "##";
$password = "####";
$pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=###', $username, $password);
$pdo->setAttribute( PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION );
$sth = $pdo->prepare('
SELECT name, lname, fname, picpath, email
FROM Department, Professor
WHERE pID = ?

    ;');
$sth->execute(array(
    $pID
));
```

**The other php code:**

```
if($sth->rowCount() > 0) {
                        $row = $sth->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);                  
     <div class='professor_pic'>
                            <img src='{$row['picpath']}' />
                        </div><!-- /professor_pic -->
                        <div class='professor_desc'>
                            <span class='one' style='float:left; padding:5px 0 0 5px;'><strong>Department:</strong> {$row['name']} </span><br>

    } else {
                        echo "No results.";
                    }
                    unset($sth);
                    ?>
```

[image: department table]
[image: professor table]

Why arent these two fields 'picpath' and 'name' being pulled?? Its not throwing any error. Above are the two db fields:

Comment: Your "other code" mixes PHP and HTML and is thus invalid. Further, your question doesn't make sense.

Comment: Why do you have "FROM Department, Professor" ?

Comment: Did you bother checking if the query actually succeeded?

Answer (score 0):

I suspect you have numerous errors with your initial SQL Query.

I suggest you read up on [MySQL JOIN](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html). Considering I understood how that query was supposed to be run try this:

```
SELECT d.name, p.lname, p.fname, p.picpath, p.email FROM Professor p JOIN Department d ON d.dID = p.dID WHERE p.pID = ?
```